# Minimize the difference of the distance between points on the line

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, distance, points

My problem is as follows:
Given n points on a line segment and a threshold k, pick the points on the line so that would minimize the average difference of the distance between each consecutive point and the threshold.

For example:
If we were given an array of points n = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9], k = 3

Output: [0, 2, 6, 9]

Explanation: when we choose this path, the difference from the threshold in each interval is [1, 1, 0] which gets an average of .66 difference.
If I chose [0, 2, 5, 8, 9], the differences would be [1, 0, 0, 2], which averages to .75.

I understand enough dynamic programming to consider several solutions including memorization and depth-first search, but I was hoping someone could offer a specific algorithm with the best efficiency.

Comment: In your example, why not just pick [6,9] to get an average of 0? Do you have to pick a certain number of points?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, I have to start from 0 and reach the last value, which in this case, is 9.